# Symfony4 bundle creation - impossible to generate a config file

Tags: symfony, config

A code demo from this problem is visible on : [GitHub](https://github.com/DeschampsJeremy/owner-test-bundle/tree/0.0.3) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/owner/test-bundle), please consult v0.0.3.

My problem : I want to generate a config\packages\owner_test.yaml file when I run :

> composer require owner/test-bundle:0.0.3

But Composer display an error :

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "owner_test" (in "C:\Users\USER\PROJECT\vendor\owner\test-bundle\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\owner_test.yaml"). Looked for namespace "owner_test", found "none".

Root key and bundle name is corrects and I have read all documentation finded, but nothing is right :

- https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles/configuration.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles/extension.html

Thanks for help

Comment: Bundles do not have a configuration file. Instead, you create a Configuration object which gives you your default configuration information.  owner_test.yaml goes in the application and allows you to override the Configuration values.

Comment: Thanks, but I try and nothing works. Can you show me an example of a very simple bundle with configuration variables in YAML. I can't find anything clear on Github ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: https://github.com/cerad/bundle4

The bundle source is in the src-owner directory

What you are missing and perhaps not fully understanding is the bundle's [Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html#processing-the-configs-array) class:

```
namespace Owner\TestBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('owner_test');
        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('isDisplay')->defaultTrue()->end()
                ->booleanNode('someBoolean')->defaultTrue()->end()
            ->end()
        ;
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

The Configuration class is used to setup default config values for your bundle.  These values can be overridden at the application level via a config/packages/owner_test.yaml.  Your bundle will not have it's own config yaml file.  Things just don't work that way.

Your extension then becomes:

```
namespace Owner\TestBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;

class OwnerTestExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Has what is in config/packages/owner_test.yaml
        dump($configs);

        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        dump($config);

        // At this point you would use $config to define your parameters or services

    }
}
```

Study the dump outputs and read the docs until you understand what is happening as the config is processed.  Just use "bin/console cache:clear".  I added a second config value just to make it a bit easier to understand.  You will probably want to add more.

At this point it up to you to add code to transfer your config values to the ContainerBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's running, thanxs very much ;)

I not sure it's the best practice, can you correct me if needed ?

Your code is perfect, for make a test I just add :

A test config variable :

```
#config\services.yaml
parameters:
    testParam: 42
```

A test env variable :

```
#.env
SECRET_TEST_KEY=abcde
```

This line on back your file for send the bundle config to APP :

```
#src-owner\DependencyInjection\OwnerTestExtension.php
$container->setParameter('owner_test', $config);
```

A PHP script (added just for simulate a real script construction) :

```
#src-owner\Services\OwnerTestService.php
<?php

namespace Owner\TestBundle\Services;

class OwnerTestService
{
    private $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function getBundleConfig()
    {
        return $this->config['someBoolean'];
    }
    function getAppConfig()
    {
        return  $this->config['testParam'];
    }
}
```

A controller for run the test :

```
#src\Controller\TestController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Owner\TestBundle\Services\OwnerTestService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function show()
    {
        $config = array_merge(['testParam' => $this->getParameter('testParam')], $this->getParameter('owner_test'));
        $ownerTestService = new OwnerTestService($config);
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>BUNDLE CONFIG : ' . $ownerTestService->getBundleConfig() . ', APP CONFIG : ' . $ownerTestService->getAppConfig()  .  ', ENV : ' . $_ENV['SECRET_TEST_KEY'] . '</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

The result is perfect, I can use all my configuration (and env) in bundle :)